# Errors on grunt build using google-api-nodejs-client with webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, google-api-nodejs-client, google-api-js-client

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis in a ReactJS Webpack app. It does have a warning that it's an alpha version, so problems are to be expected, and here's the one I'm having.

`npm install googleapis --save` installed `googleapis` ok, 
added `"googleapis": "^2.0.2"` to my package.json, but when I run `grunt build` I get the following warnings (followed by lots of errors which I'll post upon request, as it is a lot of text):

```
WARNING in ./~/googleapis/apis/index.js
Critical dependencies:
41:23-44 the request of a dependency is an expression
@ ./~/googleapis/apis/index.js 41:23-44

WARNING in ./~/googleapis/~/request/~/hawk/~/hoek/lib/index.js
Critical dependencies:
403:34-60 the request of a dependency is an expression
@ ./~/googleapis/~/request/~/hawk/~/hoek/lib/index.js 403:34-60
```

The offending line in `~/googleapis/apis/index.js` is:

```
var Endpoint = require(endpointPath);
```

One of the errors I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./~/googleapis/~/request/~/hawk/~/hoek/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/dev/wwb-web-app/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/hoek/lib
 @ ./~/googleapis/~/request/~/hawk/~/hoek/lib/index.js 3:9-22
```

Code that requires googleapis in my React component:

```
var gapi = require('googleapis');
```

*Note: Any other code from the component can be provided on request, but I don't believe it's relevant to this issue.*

My `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"aws-sdk": "^2.0.21",
"chalk": "^0.5.0",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.2-5",
"cryptojs": "^2.5.3",
"envify": "^1.2.1",
"fluxxor": "1.5.1",
"googleapis": "^2.0.2",
"imports-loader": "^0.6.3",
"jquery": "~2.1.1",
"moment": "^2.8.3",
"react": "0.11.1",
"react-bootstrap": "0.12.0",
"react-router": "0.5.2",
"react-router-bootstrap": "0.5.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"connect-livereload": "^0.4.0",
"css-loader": "^0.7.0",
"es6-promise": "^1.0.0",
"esrever": "^0.1.0",
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
"grunt-contrib-less": "~0.11.4",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
"grunt-git": "^0.2.14",
"grunt-gitinfo": "^0.1.6",
"grunt-karma": "^0.8.3",
"grunt-lesslint": "^1.1.13",
"grunt-rsync": "^0.6.1",
"grunt-ssh": "^0.11.2",
"grunt-webpack": "^1.0.8",
"jssha": "^1.5.0",
"jsx-loader": "^0.10.2",
"karma": "^0.12.17",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.7",
"karma-coverage": "^0.2.7",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
"karma-js-coverage": "^0.4.0",
"karma-osx-reporter": "^0.1.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.2",
"karma-webpack": "^1.2.1",
"load-grunt-tasks": "^0.6.0",
"style-loader": "^0.6.4",
"time-grunt": "^1.0.0",
"webpack": "^1.4.15"
}
```

npm version 2.5.1

node version v0.12.1

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a working answer, but am also looking for one.  Are you dmk12 on GitHub?  If not, take a look at this issue:

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/403

It looks like part of the problem is that the library has a line

`var Endpoint = require(endpointPath);`

which has to be evaluated, as `endpointPath` is a variable.  Unfortunately, the issue says they likely aren't going to change this behavior, as it makes their code more flexible.  One person (maybe you?) suggested working around this by loading the APIs via `<script>` tag in `index.html`, but that doesn't work for us --- my team and I wants to use the API from server-side code.

The hunt for an answer continues.

Comment: Yup, I'm dmk12 on Github, replied to your comment there. The hunt continues indeed.

Comment: Does anyone find an answers to this ? got the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified by the [comments of the project team,](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/403#issuecomment-211153097) browser usage is unsupported for the google-api-nodejs-client project. It's for server-side use only.

To solve the broader problem of how to use Google APIs with a React Webpack app, the [NuclearMail](https://github.com/ianobermiller/nuclearmail) Redux-based Gmail client provides an example.

At NuclearMail’s entry point, [`index.html`](https://github.com/ianobermiller/nuclearmail/blob/master/index.html) loads the Webpack bundle followed by the Google API load with a `handleGoogleClientLoad` callback:

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleGoogleClientLoad"></script>
```

That callback is defined in [`src/API.js`](https://github.com/ianobermiller/nuclearmail/blob/bf1d0cf2f1dc1e5656e5e34761adc68fbbc77df4/src/API.js):

```js
/* global gapi */

import ActionType from './ActionType';
import store from './store';

window.handleGoogleClientLoad = function() {
  tryAuthorize(true);
};

function tryAuthorize(immediate) {
  store.dispatch({type: ActionType.Authorization.REQUEST});
  gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
      /*eslint-disable camelcase*/
      client_id: '108971935462-ied7vg89qivj0bsso4imp6imhvpuso5u.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      /*eslint-enable*/
      scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
      immediate
    },
    whenAuthenticated
  );
}

function whenAuthenticated(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    store.dispatch({type: ActionType.Authorization.SUCCESS});
    gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', whenLoaded);
  } else {
    store.dispatch({type: ActionType.Authorization.FAILURE});
  }
}
```